# using a char value to compare to a variable name in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, char

I am trying to solve one of the Euler Project problems using c# ([problem 22](http://projecteuler.net/problem=22)). Though I have run into a problem. It's probably worth noting I am relatively new to programming, especially c#.

I need to come up with a word score for a set of strings that I have. This involves summing up the score of each letter in a a word, e.g. a=1, b=2, c=3 and so on. To do this I have assigned all 26 letters of the alphabet as variables with the relevant scores. I then want to compare each letter in the word with the relevant variables of the same name. However what I am left with is a char data type, what's the best way for me to compare the character to the relevant variable, and then use the variable value in my integer calculation. I have included the code I have so far below, with the problem occuring in the last 2 lines excluding braces. (I have had a quick look, and it appears this is not supported in c++, though i'm not sure about c#). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\john\Downloads\names.txt");
//Console.WriteLine(lines[1]);

char[] delimiterChars = { ',', '\t' };

string text = lines[0];

string[] names = text.Split(delimiterChars);
Console.WriteLine("{0} words in text:", names.Length);
Array.Sort(names);

int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 3;
int d = 4;
int e = 5;
int f = 6;
int g = 7;
int h = 8;
int i = 9;
int j = 10;
int k = 11;
int l = 12;
int m = 13;
int n = 14;
int o = 15;
int p = 16;
int q = 17;
int r = 18;
int s = 19;
int t = 20;
int u = 21;
int v = 22;
int w = 23;
int x = 24;
int y = 25;
int z = 26;

int[] nameTotal;

for (int count = 0; count < names.Length; count++)
{
    string name = names[count];
    int total = 0;
    for (int count2 = 0; count2 < name.Length; count2++)
    {             
        nameTotal[count] = name.Substring(count2) + total;
        total = total + nameTotal[count];
    }
}
```

Comment: `int letterIndex = ch - 'A';`  C# counts from 0.

Comment: Including the context here was a good idea, since your direct question is misguided.

Comment: See this line `for (int count2 = 0; count2 > name.Length; count2++)`. `>` or `<` ?

Comment: Yes you are right it shoukd be <, thanks for that :)

Comment: Also thanks for all the speedy responses, i wasnt expecting such full and comprehensive answers. I will try then when i get hone from work. Thanks for all the help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by taking advantage of the layout of the standard [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

In ASCII, the 'a' character has a decimal value of 97.  Lower-case letters then continue up until 122.

Therefore, you can easily convert an 'a' char value to your required value by using:

```
char charToConvert = 'a';
int requiredValue = (int)charToConvert - 96;
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning 26 variables for each letter, create an `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` where the `TKey` is the character and the `TValue` is whatever value you assign. Then you can access the value by passing in the character much more easily.

Comment: Even reflection doesn't let you access local variables by name.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: Hmm, I guess you're right. I guess `LocalVariableInfo` doesn't store the local variables names. Interesting...

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate the sum of the letters in a name, you can also use Linq (just an example):

```
string name = "ABCD";
int sum = name.Select(letter => letter - 'A' + 1).Sum();
```

You can perform calculations with letters just like with integers in C#. 
The Select method (which is an extension method from Linq) projects each letter of the string to it's corresponding value. These values are then summed by the extension method Sum().

Edit: As jlafay pointed out, you can omit the Select call and put the projection into the Sum method:

```
name.Sum(letter => letter - 'A' + 1)
```

And regarding your original question: You can't access the name of a local variable, even with reflection. That information is not included in the metadata of the compiled code.

Comment: Btw, the Select() call is completely unnecessary. You can do the same thing with solely invoking Sum() with the same lambda that was in your Select().

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SO
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            var text = wc.DownloadString("http://projecteuler.net/project/names.txt");

            var names = Regex.Matches(text, "[A-Z]+").Cast<Match>()
                .Select(x => x.Value)
                .OrderBy(x => x)
                .Select((name, inx) => new
                {
                    Name = name,
                    Score = name.Sum(c => c - 'A' + 1) * (inx + 1)
                });

            foreach (var n in names)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", n.Name, n.Score);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea why this got down voted, this answer is the correct solution to the problem - and it uses only one LINQ line! Amazing

Comment: @downvoter I guess you think it is a homework. My assumption is it isn't. Care to comment?

Comment: Just to clarify, this isnt homework, i am just doing this for my own enjoyment

Comment: incidentally, this doesn't seem to work.... At least with the solution it gives me, i can't pass the problem 22 :/ The value for COLIN is as it should be. Thoughts, L.B.?

Comment: Okay so through some debugging I've found out that LINQ uses culture-specific sorting, and my language happens to have diagraphs - so ANJA goes after ANNE, because 'nj' is counted as one character. This gives a slightly different order, which in turn results in an incorrect answer... After finding that, all i had to do was `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US", false);`.... hope it helps someone